# What does Standard Input in linux mean?

Tags: c, linux

My assignment is to write a version of `cat` command in Linux using C. unlike the `cat` command, my version of `cat` won't work with standard input. My question is what doest it mean by saying "`cat` won't work with standard input". Please include examples. Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: standard input in any platform usually means keyboard

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/standard_input.html

Comment: @haris, you are tragically mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means you don't have to work with stdin.  Meaning you don't have to handle the case where someone can just type "mycat" then type data followed by ^D to close the file and save it.  Also should mean you don't have to handle data being piped to it.  Looks like all you have to do is read the file passed as a parameter and print it to the console.